# changing the dark mode color in chakra ui

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am using the ["dark mode" feature](https://chakra-ui.com/color-mode) provided by the [Chakra UI library](https://chakra-ui.com/). However, I can't figure out how to change the "dark mode" colors. In the documentation, I see that Chakra UI is based on something called "[styled-system](https://styled-system.com/)", so I tried to pass a new `theme` to `themeProvider` like this:

```
const theme = {
  ...defaultTheme,
  modes: {
    dark: {
      background: '#000',
    },
  },
};
```

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={theme}></ThemeProvider>
```

However, that didn't work. I also tried to wrap the `modes` object with a `colors` object, but that didn't work either. How can I customize the "dark mode" colors?

Comment: heads up that this question is a few years old and I have found the answer's code to be a bit outdated due to chakra updates over the years. this link might be helpful https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/color-mode

Answer (score 24, accepted):

in the latest version of chakra ui we can overwrite colors this way

```
import { mode } from '@chakra-ui/theme-tools';
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/core';

const styles = {
  global: props => ({
    body: {
      color: mode('gray.800', 'whiteAlpha.900')(props),
      bg: mode('gray.100', '#141214')(props),
    },
  }),
};

const components = {
  Drawer: {
    // setup light/dark mode component defaults
    baseStyle: props => ({
      dialog: {
        bg: mode('white', '#141214')(props),
      },
    }),
  },
};

const theme = extendTheme({
  components,
  styles,
});

export default theme;
```

then we pass the `theme` into `ChakraProvider`

Comment: thanks for this. How can I also change the `colors` based on this? For example right now I override `colors` in `extendTheme` with `colors: {text: '#000'}`. I want 'text` to be black on light mode and white on dark mode. And I'm using it like `<Text color={'text'}>...</Text>`

Answer (score 1):

As doc say (and it actually works), you also need to wrap your component with another **ColorModeProvider**.

```
 <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
      <ColorModeProvider><YourCompoent/></ColorModeProvider>
 </ThemeProvider>
```

And use the hook called **useColorMode** inside your component (or nested if you wish) to get current color mode and toggle between.

```
const { colorMode, toggleColorMode } = useColorMode();
```

Comment: It seems that the ChakraProvider replaces both the ThemeProvider and the ColorModeProvider in current versions of Chakra-UI https://chakra-ui.com/docs/migration#2-update-the-themeprovider

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to override only the dark mode background without affecting the default value of the light mode you can retrieve the theme props like the following:

```
import type { StyleFunctionProps } from '@chakra-ui/styled-system';
import { mode } from '@chakra-ui/theme-tools';

const styles = {
  global: (props: StyleFunctionProps) => ({
    body: {
      // sets a custom bg color for dark mode only
      bg: mode(
        // light mode value retrieved from theme
        props.theme.semanticTokens.colors['chakra-body-bg']._light,
        // your custom value for dark mode
        '#252C32',
      )(props),
    },
  }),
};
```